# Spree cannot upload product images on Windows

Tags: image, product, spree

### First Problem

I'm new to Spree and trying to upload product images from admin. I'm getting following error when I try to upload a small JPG image:

> Attachment has contents that are not what they are reported to be

After researching, I found that **paperclip** gem is having problem on Windows.

To resolve this issue, I created a file app\models\spree\image_decorator.rb but what to do here:

```
Spree::Image.class_eval do
validates_attachment :attachment,
                   :presence => true,
                   :content_type => { :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png image/gif) }
end
```

What to do here?

### Second Problem

My products are not loading on the spree\shared_products.html.erb.

I created taxon Women => Bottom => Crop under Category taxonomy.

Then I created a new Product, created its variants, set each variant inventory. Then I assigned the taxon Women => Bottom => Crop to this product.

Answer (score 0):

The first part is solved by adding following lines to my **config\initializers\spree.rb** file:

```
module Paperclip
 class MediaTypeSpoofDetector
   def spoofed?
     false
   end
 end
end
```

For the second part, I find it strange that if I don't provide value for **Available On** field, the product will not display on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for this failing on my box was that windows does not have an equivalent command for "File" to determine file type.

The following steps worked for me.

1. I installed cygwin on my windows machine.
2. I updated the PATH variable to include the cygwin/bin location.
3. I also updated the config/environments/development.rb file to include   *Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16; C:\cygwin64\bin'*

Hope that helps.